# Postgresql How do I join these tables to get the correct output?

Tags: postgresql, join, null, left-join

I am trying to find out which people are noted as being principal actors in a movie, but aren't noted as playing a character in that movie.

The schema I have is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.movies (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    year_made public.yeartype NOT NULL,
    runtime public.minutes,
    rating double precision,
    nvotes public.counter
);

CREATE TABLE public.people (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    year_born public.yeartype,
    year_died public.yeartype
);

CREATE TABLE public.plays (
    movie_id integer NOT NULL,
    person_id integer NOT NULL,
    "character" text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.principals (
    movie_id integer NOT NULL,
    ordering public.counter NOT NULL,
    person_id integer NOT NULL,
    role text NOT NULL
```

So far the query I have used works for some actors, however I think I have done the joins incorrectly as there is another actor who is a principal actor but is given a character which it shouldn't have (character name is from another movie they were in). This is my query:

```
select name as actor, movies.title as movie,character
from principals
inner join people on principals.person_id=people.id
inner join movies on principals.movie_id=movies.id
left outer join plays on principals.person_id=plays.person_id
where principals.role = 'actor' and character is null
```

Can anyone help me with this?

This is a summary of results and the join adds all the persons character names to every movie they were principal in.
[image: Results]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NVRLiYBVbKuiazynx9Egav7c4_VHFEzP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You could use `WHERE NOT EXISTS(... FROM plays WHERE ...)`  instead of the LEFT JOIN (technically it is the same, but in practially it  can be easier to read/understand)

Comment: `sample` data is **not** a db dump, choose a few rows from each table and supply this as inserts or create a useable fiddle. See [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a second join condition is required for table `plays` as shown in bold below:

```
FROM principals
    LEFT JOIN plays ON principals.person_id = plays.person_id
        AND principles.movie_id = plays.movie_id
WHERE principals.role = 'actor'
    AND plays.person_id IS NULL
```

However I feel that a `not exists` approach will make this query easier to understand:

```
SELECT
      people.name AS actor
    , movies.title AS movie
    , plays.character
FROM principals
INNER JOIN people ON principals.person_id = people.id
INNER JOIN movies ON principals.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE principals.ROLE = 'actor'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM plays
        WHERE principals.person_id = plays.person_id
            AND principals.movie_id = plays.movie_id
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re pretty close, but need to also join plays using movie.id:

```
select name as actor, movies.title as movie
from principals
join people on principals.person_id=people.id
join movies on principals.movie_id=movies.id
left join plays on principals.person_id=plays.person_id
  and movies.id=principals.movie_id
where principals.role = 'actor'
and character is null
```

Removed character from select because it’s always null.

Comment: I tried this code @Bohmian and it still didnt work. I have noticed that it adds the Character names to every single movie (4 times) that they're principal in. I have updated the question with a screenshot of the results.

Comment: There’s more going on with the data than you’ve described: Please show sample data. Visit http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create a fiddle there with your schema and data and post the link in the question.

Comment: I couldn't add to sqlfiddle as the data is too big so I linked it to my google drive.

Comment: Do not even try to add all the data. Select 4-5 rows for each table that demonstrate the problem.